# Using an AND function as a while loop test in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop

```
while(Number_Of_Fruits > 0 & null <11);

{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Insert a Number Between 1 and 10");
    Number_Of_Fruits = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
/*Rest Of Code*/
```

What I need to do is make sure that the test only comes out as valid only when the number is over 0 and less tan 11. For some reason I get weird results when I get a failed while test when I put in 3 or above.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Logical and (`&&`) should be used. Also, `null < 11` is invalid syntax .. not sure where `null` came from there.

Comment: So the And's should be in parenthesis

Comment: @user2864740 using `&` versus `&&` makes no difference logically.

Comment: What I don't get is why this would work AT ALL??

Comment: @D Stanley: I always learned that & is a bitwise AND operator while && is a logical AND comparison operator.  Could you explain how these do the same thing?  I'm intrigued.

Comment: @DStanley ".. *should* be used." And it *does* make a difference semantically; just not in *this case*. The usage should be corrected now - using `&` in code here is a beginners mistake, not an intentional decision.

Comment: @Scottie C# defines `&` and `|` over `bool`. The difference is that they are eagerly evaluated. Using `&&` and `||` is thus usually the correct choice.

Comment: @Scottie when comparing booleans `&&` is a "short-circuiting" AND - it does not evaluate the second condition if the first is false.  `&` will compare both conditions even if the firs is false.

Comment: So should I be using a &&? I'm really new to this lol

Comment: @user3063971 Unless there is a good reason not to - yes :) See [Logical AND Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6s3h5a7.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: @user2864740 it makes a _semantic_ difference but not a _logical_ one - the output will always be the same with the same inputs.  If the inputs have no side-effects then it makes NO difference.

Comment: So Would this be valid? :    while(Number_Of_Fruits > 0 && < 11);

Comment: @DStanley I am done with this conversation. That is twice what I have said has been undermined without cause: ".. it *does* make a difference semantically; *just not in this case*."

Comment: @user3063971 No - that is not. `<` (and `&&`) is a binary operator and requires an expression on both sides. That would result in a syntax error. Just see the answers already :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following line of code from...

```
while(Number_Of_Fruits > 0 & null <11);
```

to

```
while(Number_Of_Fruits > 0 && Number_Of_Fruits < 11);
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should use && instead of & and Number_Of_Fruits instead of null.
while(Number_Of_Fruits > 0 && Number_Of_Fruits <11);

```
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Insert a Number Between 1 and 10");
            Number_Of_Fruits = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Comment: Oh I see, I didnt write Number_of_Fruits<11 I just wrote <11

Answer (score 1):

The condition states *the number is over 0 and less tan 11*, so I have no idea why you're comparing `11` with `null` there...

```
while(Number_Of_Fruits > 0 && Number_Of_Fruits < 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:** You should not close the while loop with `semicolon ;` . if you close it it will not go inside the loop , but you should use it in `do-while` loop.
**Problem 2:**  you should use double ampersand `&&` for Logical AND Operation.
**Problem 3:** You should not compare `null` with `integer`.

**Solution 1:**

```
while(Number_Of_Fruits > 0 && Number_Of_Fruits <11)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Insert a Number Between 1 and 11");
        Number_Of_Fruits = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

**Solution 2:** i think `do-while` loop suits best to you.

```
        int Number_Of_Fruits = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Insert a Number Between 1 and 11");
            Number_Of_Fruits = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if(Number_Of_Fruits > 0 && Number_Of_Fruits < 11) 
            {
            //do whatever you want
            }

        } while (Number_Of_Fruits > 0 && Number_Of_Fruits < 11) ;
```

**Solution 3:** if you want to handle the user input in better way you can use `Int32.TryParse()` instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`

```
        int Number_Of_Fruits = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Insert a Number Between 1 and 11");
            if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out Number_Of_Fruits))
            {
            if(Number_Of_Fruits > 0 && Number_Of_Fruits < 11) 
            {
            //do whatever you want
            }
            }
            else
            {
             Console.WriteLine("User Input is Invalid (not a number) -> Terminating");
            }


        } while (Number_Of_Fruits > 0 && Number_Of_Fruits < 11) ;
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the semicolon (explicitly) - that would have resulted in a different post momentarily!

Comment: I tried the do while one but now its doing the logic wrong... no number between 1 and 10 works

Comment: @user3063971: no it works perfectly , please check it once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while(Number_Of_Fruits > 0 && Number_Of_Fruits <11)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Insert a Number Between 1 and 10");
        Number_Of_Fruits = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    /*Rest Of Code*/
```

visit [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx hope it helps you. This is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

try the TryParse !

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Number_Of_Fruits;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Insert a Number Between 1 and 10");
            }
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Number_Of_Fruits) || Number_Of_Fruits < 1 || Number_Of_Fruits > 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked :) what does the TryParse exactly do? also what does out do?